# Boolean not returning as expected in String.Contains()?

Tags: java, string, compare, contain

I have this sample from my project and I need to know why the result is what it is.

```
public class Main 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //url: https://classicpartyrentals.com/products/24681-gothic-silver-coffee-cup, websiteList: http://classicpartyrentals.com/, URL Contains Returns bool: false
        String url = "https://classicpartyrentals.com/products/24681-gothic-silver-coffee-cup";
        String contains = "http://classicpartyrentals.com/";
        System.out.println("Returns bool: " + url.contains(contains));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Returns bool: false
```

Comment: `https` and `http`...

Comment: you have `https` in your url whule you look for `http`in the contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is always doing what you ask it to do:

```
 String url = "https://classicpartyrentals.com/products/24681-gothic-
```

but

```
 String contains = "http://classicpartyrentals.com/";
```

http**s** versus http!

So the **real** answer is: especially when you are a beginner, chances that your code uncovered "some Java bug" is relatively small (very close to zero in reality!)

There is a much higher chance that **your** assumptions are wrong. You either don't fully understand the methods you are calling, or there is a *subtle* flaw in your input data.

Finally: also work on your *naming*. *contains* isn't a very good name here; you better call it *expectedUrl*, or something alike!

Comment: Oh i see thank you!! hard to catch things like that sometimes.

Comment: Sure. The way to go there is to have some other human person look at your code. But please understand that SO is not the ... well, perfect place ... for such inquiries. Better turn to your peers/coworkers and ask them to have a look!

Comment: Seems like this was the perfect solution for me. Not sure why this wouldn't be the place for help. I understand it would be quicker for me to ask another person but i asked people. They missed it too. I also do not always have access to someone to ask. After all this site is made to help with this sort of stuff anyway.

Comment: The real point is: its really just a subtle typo like bug. That is why you got those close requests. In that sense: feel free to accept the answer you like the most, and be happy that you didn't so too many downvotes so far ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I knew it would be something stupid but staring at it for hours was not helping. And contains is a method that String has already I didn't make it up.

Comment: I am not asking you change the name of an existing method. That one is fine. I am saying that you shouldnt call your **variable** "contains"!

Comment: Oh yeah. That makes sense. Thank you for the advice on everything BTW.

Answer (score 1):

In your Code Url "https://classicpartyrentals.com/products/24681-gothic-silver-coffee-cup" contains https

but your compare string "http://classicpartyrentals.com/" contain http so its not match and return false